# Handling db errors and showing to the user

Tags: php, database, web

I have a very simple question.

Is there any way to relate database errors to a well formed warning?

What I mean is for example a user is registering in a site and the username chosen by him/her is already been taken so when saving to the database the following error happens:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'peter' for key 'username'
```

I really don't want to show this to the user but something more like:
"The chosen username has already been taken"

What's the best way to identify the error and output a well formed warning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a select query first to check if the username was taken. Only if it's not do you insert it.

Ideally you lock the table, or use transactions, but practically it's probably OK if the two queries are right near each other.

Comment: Isn't there a more general way? Not only for duplicated entries?

Comment: How would you know in advance what the database error would be? What if the database said "Disk full" would you treat that as duplicate username? In properly written code you should never expect database errors. Any error should abort the code fully, and not try to ask the user to modify the input. Don't try to do this in a more general fashion.Just always add "guard code" around database queries to make sure they can never fail in the normal course of activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could first check if the username is taken:

```
$num_rows_aff = SELECT * FROM table where username = 'peter';

If($num_rows_aff > 0)
{
  // Username exists, Output "Username is taken";
}else{
  // Insert username into database
}
```

Comment: I thought about that but I wanted a more general approach...not only for duplicated fields.
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing some basic database functions, like exists() and such, which you could pass a custom error string. Something like this:

```
<?php

class DB {

    private $_instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_instance = new MySQLI('server','username','password','database');
    }

    public function exists($sql, $msg) {
        $result = $this->_instance->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            throw new FrontDBException($msg);
        }

        return false;
    }

}

class FrontDBException extends Exception {
    public function __toString() {
        echo($this->getMessage());
    }
}

$db = new DB();

try {
    $db->exists('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username="' . $username . "'",
            'Username is already taken.');
} catch(FrontDBException $e) {
    echo($e);
}

?>
```

But you can't really predict the incoming errors, when you are just doing basic queries, you need to sort of wrap it in specific functions.

Comment: Well i suppose, you could, the 1062 is probably a code for 'duplicate entry'. But you would have to write error messages for all codes. And even regular expressions, if you want to take it further.